# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. for SQlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite

I keep getting the below error in rails on windows when I try to make a new rails app? It fails when it gets to installing sqlite3.

```
current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190220-14164-174xy0j.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

I have sqlite3 installed on my machine and I am using windows 10. I have attempted ot run the gem install sqlite3 command like it prompts me to but it still fails what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got the same message when tried to install SQLite gem without MinGW gem installed already

```
C:\Sites>ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
```

Install it and try again
If you DON'T have installed RailsInstaller only Ruby DevKit it should work. If not please try uninstalling it first, removing the remaining folders and installing rails by command `gem install rails`

Comment: My Ruby version is Ruby26-x64 on it the MinGW and msys2 executables are already included in C:\Ruby26-x64\msys64 but if the version 25 doesn't include it download it with the MinGW Installer Manager from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Install_MinGW

Answer (score 6):

Try this
`$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` 
then,
`$ bundle install`

Comment: Thanks.  This did the trick for me on Ubuntu 20.04 as well

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you use different rails version.

Solution is change version of sqlite to 1.3.6:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

After this change run command:

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling all the versions of the sqlite3 gem from the system and reinstalling only version 1.4.0