# Error when executing the "bundle install" in the command prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I was following the [rails tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and encountered this error. The error says that sqlite3.h is missing. But I had downloaded the sqlite3 from the official website and installed it properly. Why `sqlite3.h` is missing? How do I fix this? Do I have to download a specific file called `sqlite3.h` to get it working?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Xu Zeng>cd blog

C:\Users\Xu Zeng\blog>rails server
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.1.7) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

C:\Users\Xu Zeng\blog>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.7.0
Using minitest 5.13.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.6
Using activesupport 5.1.7
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.7 (x64-mingw32)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.5
Using loofah 2.4.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 5.1.7
Using rack 2.0.8
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.1.7
Using nio4r 2.5.2
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.7
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.1.7
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.1.7
Using activemodel 5.1.7
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.7
Using public_suffix 4.0.2
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using regexp_parser 1.6.0
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.30.0
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using thor 1.0.1
Fetching railties 5.1.7
Installing railties 5.1.7
Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
Fetching ffi 1.11.3 (x64-mingw32)
Installing ffi 1.11.3 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching jbuilder 2.9.1
Installing jbuilder 2.9.1
Fetching puma 3.12.2
Installing puma 3.12.2 with native extensions
Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
Installing sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Fetching rails 5.1.7
Installing rails 5.1.7
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching rubyzip 2.0.0
Installing rubyzip 2.0.0
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Fetching sass 3.7.4
Installing sass 3.7.4
Fetching tilt 2.0.10
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
Fetching selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Installing selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.2
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20191229-3908-1eyuunw.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

the mkmf.log is like this

```
"pkg-config --exists sqlite3"
package configuration for sqlite3 is not found
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -DTAINTING_SUPPORT conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby26-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby260  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -DTAINTING_SUPPORT  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <sqlite3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Are you using Window OS?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817408/938947 , probably can answer your problem

Comment: I am using Window OS

Comment: It looks like the Ruby DevKit is not properly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When installing some gems, if it failed to install, I think your system missing some native requirements. In case of SQLite3, I think you need to install sqlite3, sqlite3 client first in your OS system.